# Amazon EC2 AMI pre-configured with Django Stack

Tags: python, django, web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

What is the best available EC2 AMI configured with

- Django Stack
- MySql Installed and configured
- Apache or any other Server

After searching I have found only one [bitniami djangostack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack). Have any of you ever tried it. Are there any other options.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be better take a standard well known image and install the software.  The Ubuntu installation is quick and easy.  In my case I've had no trouble using the ubuntu-maverick-10.10-amd64-server AMI from Canonical to build up a Pylons stack.  For your requirements you could start with this AMI and then using

```
sudo tasksel --section server
```

and selecting the LAMP components (space-bar to select) you get Apache and MySQL.  Then

```
sudo apt-get install python-django python-django-doc
```

gets you Django. See more details [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Django).

Of course custom configuration is another matter -- which for my level of Apache experience is a slow process.

Comment: With Apache, use mod_wsgi, (`apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi`). For further information, see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/.

Comment: @Nate. Right. Much of my struggle with Pylons deployment was choosing among the dozen or so deployment options before landing on mod_wsgi.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Right now, though, I am staying with bitniami django stack.

Comment: Wasted nearly 4-5 hours after using bitniami djangostack AMI, finally got my django project working using this guide.. http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/08/notes-django-and-mysql-amazons-ec2/

Comment: @db42 Thanks, I'll bookmark this -- especially since it includes detailed MySql incantations.

Answer (score 2):

[This worked for me, so, adding it as one of the answers]

I wasted nearly 4-5 hours after using bitniami djangostack AMI, finally got my django project working using this guide:
[saltycrane.com/blog/2008/08/notes-django-and-mysql-amazons-ec2](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/08/notes-django-and-mysql-amazons-ec2/)

Comment: What kind of problems did you run into exactly?